# Getting Values from JSON list returned from Controller MVC

Tags: javascript, json, list

I'm returning a list of Bookings Class like this:

```
public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {List<Common.Booking> lst = new List<Common.Booking>();
        Common.Booking b = new Common.Booking();
        b.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        b.BeginTime = DateTime.Now;
        b.EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(40);
        b.Confirmed = false;
        b.ServiceId = Guid.NewGuid();
        b.Username = "Dirett";

        lst.Add(b);

        return Json(lst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Then from JavaScript I'm getting the list and store it in a variable:

```
var lstServices;
GetServices();
function GetServices() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Service/GetServices",
        success: function (result) {
            lstServices = result;
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
        }
    });
};
```

I'm not sure how to get the values from this list such as getting the Username, Id, ServiceId etc from the list.. I've tried different methods to get the values but they weren't successful. Anyone have an idea how to do this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your server is returning json you will need to put an extra parameter `dataType: "json"` in the jQuery.

Then, `result` will be parsed as a JSON object in the `success` function. I'm not familiar with your server languge, but you should be able to say `result.Id` (or `lstServices.Id`).

You can see what the object contains by writing `console.log(lstServices);` in the success function, the results of which will show up in your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lstServices;
GetServices();
function GetServices() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Service/GetServices",
        success: function (result) {
            lstServices = result;

var id = lstServices.Id;
var beginTime = lstServices.BeginTime;

// print out all properties using:
// console.log( lstServices )

        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
        }
    });
};
```